# How to set a file in cron job

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

I need to run a php file every minute so I tried to set a cronjob from the cpanel 
but it's sending mail with the message "could not open the input file:"

My php file is inside public_html/schoolerp/cron.php

I did:

/usr/local/bin/php -f /public_html/schoolerp/cron.php

Am I doing something wrong please tell me if I am setting it right, and if I am wrong please help me correct it ...

Answer (score 3):

- Use absolute paths
- Make sure that the script is
  accessible, check access permissions of file/directories on path
- cron by default will take all the
  output of your script and send it to
  your email

You can redirect the output of your command to file or /dev/null to prevent cron from sending email. I would suggest redirect to local file for future references, it's good for debugging and when something goes wrong.

I think something like this should do:

```
/usr/local/bin/php -f /public_html/schoolerp/cron.php > /logs/mylog.txt 2>&1
```

Redirect to mylog.txt file and append stderror to stdout so that both stderror and stdout is in log file.

Comment: Good thorough answer, much moreso than mine. +1

Comment: An additional thing to point out here is that you can set errors to be emailed to you by letting STDERR slide through (not redirecting it). MAILTO=myemail@mydomain.com should be at the top of the crontab. If STDOUT is considered an error then simply don't redirect. Much nicer than having to remember to log in and check the log.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is a complete fix, but you are using absolute pathing for '/public_html/schoolerp/cron.php', when that doesn't seem very likely to be correct. You might be looking for a relative path of 'public_html/schoolerp/cron.php' (note the lack of preceding '/'). You may just want to use the proper absolute path starting from the root of the filesystem though.